# How to get index of key/group in itertools.groupby?

Tags: python, indexing, python-itertools

When using the `groupby` function from `itertools`, is there a nice way to get the index of the `key/group` tuple?
I would like to avoid to have to do :

```
index = 0
for key, group in itertools.groupby(myList, myFunc) :
  ...
  index += 1
```

Is it possible to do something with enumerate for example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to place `key` and `group` in parenthesis:

```
for index, (key, group) in enumerate(itertools.groupby(myList, myFunc)):
```

Below is a demonstration:

```
>>> # lst represents what is returned by itertools.groupby
>>> lst = [(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)]
>>> for i, (j, k) in enumerate(lst):
...     i, j, k
...
(0, 1, 2)
(1, 3, 4)
(2, 5, 6)
>>>
```